# Difference in spacing/tab alignment between Sql-server and vim

Tags: sql-server, vim

If I open my sql file in `sql-server` it displays this:

[image]

If I open the same file in `gvim` it displays this:

[image]

How do I set things up so that the alignment of the code in the two views are the same? Ideally it would be good if I could edit long scripts using vim and if a colleague opens the file in sql-server they will see the script aligned exactly the same?

Some setting I currently have are.

In sql-server's `Tools > Options...`

[image]

In `_vimrc` I've got:

```
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set noexpandtab
```

Is it possible to to set things up so that the scripts will look the same in each application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want A and B to look the same you have to define what the desired appearance is. It can be that you want A to look like B or B to look like A or both A and B to look like C.

That desired appearance is what is lacking in your question.

- Do you want sql-server to look like GVim?

  Look around sql-server's preferences and see if you can set it to use monospaced fonts. Seriously, who wants variable-width fonts for displaying code?
- Do you want GVim to look like sql-server?

  You can't. Gvim only works with monospaced fonts which is a good thing because who wants variable-width fonts for displaying code?
- Do you want both to look like another unspecified tool?

  As long as it's based on monospaced font… maybe. What would that tool be?

Whatever, you could start by using the same values for the same options in sql-server and GVim.

Like… 4 everywhere.

Or 2.

Comment: +1 vim has aligned the fields selected in a standard manner - that's what I'd like to achieve in both. I reckon you've probably spotted the obvious place to start though - I'll change all to 2 and see what they both look like...

Comment: Ok - the "omnipresent-vimmer" strikes again. I changed both to 2 (in vim `shiftwidth=2` in sql-server `Tab size = 2 / Indent size = 2`). Then in sql-server I swapped to Consolas (monospaced). The code now aligns the same in both applications.

Comment: Note that your colleague needs a monospace font as well.

Comment: I'll let them know - as long as it looks the same in both my apps I'm happy - all I can do is _advise_ to use monospaced font.

Comment: you've probably already seen the question: I've simplified it lots now though - how do I fix this behaviour? [SO POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802259/vim-not-finding-the-end-of-the-sql-statement)